# Inverse Fourier Tranform of $e^{-|\xi|^{2s}}$ is in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, dirac-delta

**Problem**

We wish to show that $ \mathcal{F}^{-1}[ e^{-|\xi|^{2s}}] \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R^2}) $, for all $ p \in [1,\infty], \ s\in(0,1) $.

That is, we wish to show that $ (\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} | \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{2 \pi i x\cdot\xi} e^{-|\xi|^{2s}} \text{d}\xi |^p \text{d}x )^{1/p} < \infty $, for $p \in [1,\infty)$.

**My Attempt**

My thinking was that we could simply observe that $ e^{-|\xi|^{2s}} \leq 1 $, and then only consider:

$ (\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} | \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{2 \pi i x\cdot\xi} \text{d}\xi |^p \text{d}x )^{1/p} = (\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} | \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{2 \pi i x_1 \xi_1} \text{d}\xi_1 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{2 \pi i x_2 \xi_2} \text{d}\xi_2  |^p \text{d}x )^{1/p} $

We then use the fact that $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{2 \pi i x_1 \xi_1} \text{d}\xi_1 = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \delta(x_1) $.

Now, I believed that, by the usual properties of the Dirac-Delta Distribution, we could say that:

$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \delta(x_1) \text{d}x_1 = \frac{1}{2\pi} $

and thus $ (\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\frac{1}{2 \pi} \delta(x_1)| \text{d}x_1)^{1/p} = \frac{1}{2\pi} $.

However, after some research online, it's come to my attention that this is **NOT** true, and in fact the dirac delta distribution is not in $L^p$, for any $p$.

As such, I am now lost as to how I can prove the above claim. Any hints/advice appreciated. Thank you.

**Update**

The case $p = \infty$ is actually quite easy to prove, so I only need help with the case $p \in [1,\infty)$.

Comment: With $e^{-|\xi|^{2s}}\leq 1$ you throw away the good decay that your function has.

Comment: Yes, it does seem that I need to use this somehow, but I'm not sure how, since there is apparently no general formula in terms of $x$ for the inverse FT...

Comment: The inverse FT is well known to probabilists. It is the density function of a symmetric stable random variable and it does belong to every $L^{p}$.

Comment: Do you have a source/proof of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(\xi)=e^{-|\xi|^{2s}}$, where $0<s<1$. Since $f\in L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for any $q\in[1,\infty]$, we have 
$$
F=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)
\qquad\textrm{for}\quad
p\in[2,\infty],
$$ 
by the Hausdorff-Young inequality.

So far, we have only used the decay of $f$. Now we want to exploit the regularity of $f$, which is related to the decay of $F$. We start by noting that
$$
|x|^2F=c\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\Delta f),
$$
where $c$ is a constant (involving $i$, $\pi$ etc.). Compute the Laplacian of $f$ as
$$
\Delta f(\xi)=e^{-|\xi|^{2s}}(c_1|\xi|^{4s-2}+c_2|\xi|^{2s-2}),
$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are again constants. Since $s>0$, it is easy to see that $\Delta f\in L^{1+\varepsilon}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. This gives us $|x|^2F\in L^q(\mathbb{R}^2)$ for some $q<\infty$ by Hausdorff-Young, and thus 
$$
F\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)
\qquad\textrm{for}\quad
p\geq1.
$$
Let me clarify the last step a bit further. Since $F$ is smooth, it suffices to show that 
$$
\|F(x)\|_{L^1(Q)}<\infty
\qquad\textrm{with}\quad
Q=\{|x|>1\}.
$$
Thus we compute 
$$
\int_Q|F(x)|dx=\int_Q|F(x)||x|^2|x|^{-2}dx
\leq
\||x|^2F\|_{L^q(Q)}\||x|^{-2}\|_{L^{r}(Q)},
$$
where $r$ is the Hölder conjugate of $q$. The crucial point is that $r>1$, and hence $|x|^{-2}\in L^r(Q)$, because $q<\infty$.

Comment: How do you deal with the pole at $0$ of $\Delta f$?

Comment: @D.Thomine the pole is absolutely integrable. This is really the thing that gives decay to $F$.

Comment: Oh, that's on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I was wondering what was wrong with my understanding of this question.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. It has been very helpful!

However, towards the end, I believe there is a mistake. It does not seem to me, having checked an integral calculator, that $\Delta f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$. The integral is divergent for, say, $s = 0.5$.

Edit: Never mind haha. My mistake!

Comment: Having refreshed the page, I see that you have made an edit to your answer. Thank you very much for all your work! Could you please explain your last step, going from $|x|^2F \in L^q(\mathbb{R}^2)$ for sufficiently large  $q<\infty$, to $F \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)$ for $p\geq 1$?

Comment: @DavidHughes: I have updated the answer.

Comment: Why is it only $$\Delta f \in L^{1+\epsilon}(\mathbb{R}^2)$$ for $\epsilon>0$ and not for $\epsilon=0$?!

Comment: I'm also not sure I get this step right: By Hausdorff-Young it follows $\Delta f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)$ for $1<p<2$, so that $|x|^2 F \in L^q(\mathbb{R}^2)$ for some $2<q<\infty$. Maybe that is clear to you, but it is not to me that you mean it.

Comment: @Diger: It is true that $\Delta f\in L^1$, but it only implies that $|x|^2F\in L^\infty$, which would give $F\in L^p$ for $p>1$. To get this with $p=1$, we want slightly more, that is $\Delta f\in L^{1+\varepsilon}$.

Comment: It is probably not true that $\Delta f\in L^p$ for $1<p<2$. But fortunately $\Delta f\in L^p$ with some $p>1$ is enough to give $|x|^2F\in L^q$ with some $q<\infty$.

Comment: Just curious, can the Hausdorff-Young or Hölder inequality be used for any complex valued functions, when the absolute value inside the p-norm is understand in its sense to be a real valued function? So $f(t)\in\mathbb{C}$ where $t\in\mathbb{R}$ is real, but $f$ is generally complex valued.

Comment: They are valid if you replace the absolute values by the modulus, i.e., $\sqrt{\bar{z}z}$.